# What is the orange part on a scallop?

Tags: scallops

I bought some scallops and they have an orange crescent part attached to them which I haven't seen before. Is this part meant to be discarded?

Comment: A scallop without the orange thing may not be a scallop! Sometimes it's just a piece of stamped out squid. Fresh is best, get them straight out of the sea, and lightly BBQ, yummm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "roe".  More on wikipedia: [Scallop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scallop#Reproductive_cycle)

> Red roe is that of a female, and
>   white, that of a male.

It's optional if you want to eat it, personally it don't like the taste.

More on (ahem) [Yahoo Answers](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080612001621AAFgreQ)

Comment: I quite like the roe, actually.

Comment: @bikeboy389 want to share a few kilos of scallops? :)